# Can not manage flags in gParted on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, gparted

So I installed Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS a month ago and now I want to revert to Windows. I've encountered a problem while trying to do that. I used gParted to format my usb into NTFS format. I successfully did it and I managed the flags no problem, but after that I started to play with the usb. I did something and now I can not manage the flags anymore. I need to set the flags to boot.

[image]

I've unmounted it and tried to manage flags but it is grayed out :(
When I now try to burn the iso on my USB with MultiWriter it says:

[image]

Comment: Just fromat the entire disk from diskpart in the Windows installer and install as normal.

Answer (score 5):

This is most likely because you do not have an "msdos" type of partition table in place. You can correct this via "Device" ==> "Create Partition Table" ==> "msdos". Now, add your FAT/NTFS/etc partition, and you are now able to set the boot flags on it.